# How to check if a String contains a value at a particular index/position?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to validate a string of numbers and wish to check if the first number in the string is 4.
I've tried using includes but it STARTS checking from position 0 and if 4 occurs anywhere, its true which I don't want. I want to isolate it with first number.

```
if (!card_number.includes("4", 0)) {
    //show error
}
```

Comment: You can use `string.startsWith` or a regex: `^4.+$`

Comment: Use [charAt](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charat.asp). `card_number.charAt(0) === '4'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`startsWith` is for this very thing:

```
if (card_number.startsWith("4")) {
```

Or of course, `charAt` when it's just a one-character string:

```
if (card_number.charAt(0) === "4") {
```

And if you wanted to check later in the string (which I don't think you do in this case, but...), `startsWith` accepts a starting position as an optional second argument.

```
if (card_number.startsWith("4", 20)) { // Does it have "4" at index 20?
```

And again, if just loking for a single character, you can do that with `charAt`, too:

```
if (card_number.charAt(20) === "4")) { // Does it have "4" at index 20?
```

Comment: This helped but what do I do if I want a range of possible values? Say something like 51 to 55.

Comment: @Ahsan1999 - It depends on the values. For instance, `/^5[1-5]/.test(card_number)` would work for that specific one. Or grab the digits (`const [digits] = card.match(/^\d+/);`), parse as a number, and do a range check...

Answer (score 0):

includes will check matching character in string irrespective of `index`. Instead you can get the first character of the string using index , convert to number and do comparasion

```js
let strArray = ['345', '444', '456', '789'];
strArray.forEach((item) => {
  if (parseInt(item[0], 10) === 4) {
    console.log(item)
  }
})
```